# Button labels stay greyed out after setEnabled(True)

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to disable and later re-enable a bunch of QPushButtons and QRadioButtons. Disabling them using `button.setEnabled(False)` works perfectly, the button outline and label are greyed out and it's not clickable anymore.

However, after doing `button.setEnabled(True)` later, the outline returns from grey to white, but the label stays grey.

Did I miss something or is this a bug in Qt?

Comment: Please provide an working example, part of source code etc.

Comment: Turns out this is caused by the functions that tries to disable/enable the UI running in a new thread. Now I need to figure out how to call a function in the main thread from a different thread.

Comment: GUI stuff should be kept in one thread. (It's by default not thread-safe.) You may communicate between threads with signals if you use a [`Qt::QueuedConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Comment: Yes, that's probably what I need. I want the buttons to be greyed out while a calculation runs in another thread, so the main thread needs to know when the calculation has finished

Comment: @janp provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you, but I already solved the issue (see the answer I posted).

Comment: Well, your question is off-topic since you did not give the necessary information to solve it as you are using threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Turns out this problem is caused by me using multiple threads.

I solved the problem by switching from python threading to QThread and catching the started() / finished() signals of the new thread to disable/enable the UI elements.

Comment: You can also use <<WidgetName>>.repaint() options to come out of Grey after disable